Tradingview strategy indicator and heiken ashi
If I change the candlestick type to heiken ashi, then in the strategy all indicators begin to be calculated on the basis of heiken ashi, but entry and exit from the deal is taken on the opening of a regular candle or heiken ashi?
For example code of strategy
//@version=5
strategy("Supertrend Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=15)

atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[_, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

if ta.change(direction) < 0
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if ta.change(direction) > 0
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)


By default, any strategy that is added to a HA chart will enter and exit based on HA prices (i.e. fake prices). You can change this by enabling the "Using standard OHLC" setting in the strategy's properties.

